# pygame event keys are not responding even though idle is not showing an error?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init

pygame.display.init
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
human = pygame.image.load("human1.bmp")
display_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
keyboard_input = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def screen_Quit():
running = False
while not running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                keyboard_input = (90)
                print("Left arrow key has been pressed.")

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keyboard_input = (-90)
                print("Right arrow key has been pressed.")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                keyboard_input = (20)
                print("Up arrow key has been pressed.")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                keyboard_input = (-20)
                print("Down arrow key has been pressed.")

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                keyboard_input = (0)
                print("Left arrow key has been released.")

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keyboard_input = (0)
                print("Right arrow key has been released.")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                keyboard_input = (0)
                print("Up arrow key has been released.")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                keyboard_input = (0)
                print("Down arrow key has been released.")


        # this code here has been left for later --> print(event)

display_screen.blit(bg, [0,0])
display_screen.blit(human, [50,87])
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
screen_Quit()
pygame.quit
quit()
```

I don't understand the problem, I have posted my full code as the problem might be something else. The problem I've been having with the program is the event keys in python it's not responding to the input which is the keyboard I'm using pygame to create a game but cannot understand why the event keys are not working. I have checked everywhere and cannot understand. The code seems fine to me, python idle is not giving any errors I'm even getting input in the idle but the character doesn't move there should be no reason for it not to move.

Here is a picture and a link to a video that goes more in depth into the problem (I created the video myself):

[an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6xam.jpg)

Link to video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVFaiuF9KY8&feature=youtu.be

Video will most likely be more useful than image.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code sample.

Comment: Indentation? Which line should I fix the indentation @skrx

Comment: Everything in the `def screen_Quit():` function is indented incorrectly. Also, the video link doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you been working on it for 3 days I'm still learning a lot from programming and I need to get used to the pygame commands I had no idea that is what 'pygame.display.update' actually did. I truly appreciate it. @NateBronman

Comment: By the way the image is only temporary and will later be replaced by a sprite and a proper background @NateBronman

Comment: OK I will fix the video problem  @skrx

Answer (score 1):

### ***Short Answer***

Your code doesn't have any commands that tell the image to move. I fixed this and posted the full working code at the bottom. If you want a more in depth explanation, read on.

### Explanation

If that is your full code, then the problem is that first of all you don't even have any code in the first place that tells the character to move. And second of all your `pygame.display.update()` is outside the while loop, so any changes made to the screen don't show.

For every event you just told python to print a message:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
         keyboard_input = (90)
         print("Left arrow key has been pressed.")
```

What you want to do is add another line there to actually move the character.
This can be done by changing it's x and y position. I recommend using sprites for this, but for now since you are using an image, we'll just stick to that.

To change the position of an image you have to run a new `window.blit()` with the desired (x,y). This means that you will have to constantly iterate this if you're going to need to move it around a lot, so it's better to put it *INSIDE* the running while loop. So bring this part of your code on indentation forward:

```
    display_screen.blit(bg, [0,0])
    display_screen.blit(human, [50,87])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    screen_Quit()
    pygame.quit
    quit()
```

So now the screen get's regularly updated. The second thing you want to do is create 2 new variables `x` and `y`and change

`display_screen.blit(human, [50,87])`
 to 
`display_screen.blit(human, [x,y])`

This basically means that you character now gets blitted to the screen at the position YOU choose, not at a fixed position that doesn't change. So now you can add `+` to the x position whenever the left key is clicked, or `-` from the x position whenever the right key is clicked!

***Here is the full working code:***

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init

pygame.display.init
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
human = pygame.image.load("human1.bmp")
display_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
keyboard_input = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = False
x=0
y=0
moving = "none"
white = (255,255,255)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moving = "left"
                print("Left arrow key has been pressed.")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moving = "right"
                print("Right arrow key has been pressed.")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moving = "up"
                print("Up arrow key has been pressed.")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                moving = "down"
                print("Down arrow key has been pressed.")
        else:
            moving = "hello"

    if moving == "left":
        x -= 5
    if moving == "right":
        x += 5
    if moving == "up":
        y -= 5
    if moving == "down":
        y += 5

            # this code here has been left for later --> print(event)

    display_screen.blit(bg,[0,0])
    display_screen.blit(human, [x,y])
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update the position of your player and just blit it at `[50,87]`. If you want it to move, you first have to store the position, e.g. `player_pos = [50, 87]` and define variables for the velocity `velocity_x = 0`, then set the velocity in the event loop if a key gets pressed:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    velocity_x = 5
```

and update the position in the while loop:

```
player_pos[0] += velocity_x
player_pos[1] += velocity_y
```